# How can I add two iterations of items from a list to form a total (cards from a blackjack hand)

Tags: python, blackjack

PlayersHand is set up like this.

```
import random

PlayersHand = []
DealersHand = []
Ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","Ace", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
Suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
Deck = []
for num in Ranks:
    for  suit in Suits:
        card = num + ' of ' + suit
        Deck += [card]
        random.shuffle(Deck)

print()

for i in Deck:
    numval=(i[0]) 

PlayersHand = random.choices(Deck, k=2)
        print(name,"Your cards are", PlayersHand)
        DealersHand = random.choices(Deck, k=1)
        print("Dealer, your cards are Blank +",DealersHand)
        total = 0

  for i in PlayersHand:
        countval=(i[0])#to get the value of the card(perhaps need first two values for one or ten)
        print ("count is", countval);
        print("-------------")
        print(i)
    if countval == "J" or countval =="K" or countval =="Q": total +=10
    elif  countval =="A":
            total = 11
    else:
            total=countval

    print ("countval is",countval)
    print ("countval is",total)
```

In the code I put in some markers to help me understand the flow.
the i value repeats as it should but takes (the second) value and I can't seem to grab and use the first value separately so I can add them. ie countval1 added to countval2 will become total
I then need to be able to add the next new card.

I know there are better ways that I don't quite understand yet(such as dicts etc) But I 'd like to complete it like this as I've struggled so long with it!

Comment: Show how "PlayersHand" is set as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Additionally because this is a blackjack game you should seed the random generator with crypto secure bytes - `import os; random.seed(os.urandom(32))`

Comment: Thanks Eric. Don't exactly know what that is but I guess it's making it secure. I'll look it up.

Comment: I'm getting this error as the code is not converting JKQ or A into their integer values.while sum(PlayersHand) <21:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Honestly, seeding a pseudo-random number generator with a cryptographically secure random number seems silly for this project - I think it's a waste of time. You're struggling to put the project together as it is with the knowledge that you have, so why should you spend time trying to implement a feature that's only relevant in actual black jack games where, you know, people actually bet money?

Comment: Yep. Just want to get a simple working version.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the other two branches of the `if` statement, you forgot the `+` and thus instead of adding to the total (`+=`) you overwrite the value (`=`).

Assuming that `PlayersHand` is an iterable object (i.e. a list) of strings, your code should look something like this:

```
total = 0

for i in PlayersHand:
    countval = i[:2] # up to two characters

    if countval in 'JKQ':
        total += 10
    elif countval == 'A':
        total += 11
    else:
        total += int(countval) # cast a string to a number
```

Comment: tried that. Still get the error where it's adding a string to an int for sum(PlayersHand). How can I make sure JKQA take their number value and get added to total?

Comment: @PHogan Now that is a separate problem, but I would advise you create a function that returns the card's value, say `card_value` and then calculate `sum(card_value(c) for c in PlayersHand)`.

Comment: Seems like a good idea @JakuJ. I'm still learning how to use functions properly. Their logic mucks me up for some reason.  The return() gets me and It's never lined up(indented) according to the errors. Anyways I'll try it out.